# Android: softkeyboard not showing up

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have 2 EditTexts in the MainActivity Layout. If i run the application normally the 1st EditText gets focused but the softkeyboard is not openned.

but when i used this:

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        et2.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(et2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

expecting the 2nd EditText will get focus and softkeyboard will be openned.

I only get focus, but the softkeyboard is openned only when i click on the EditText.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying the [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for your activity.

For example:

```
<activity android:name=".TestingActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

You probably don't need any of the code that uses `InputMethodManager` in your Activity.

Comment: no actually my requirement is to set focus on a specific EditText and open softkeyboard- Programatically.

Comment: @wsanville, it is working in 2.2 version but not in 4.1.2. the keypad is not showing even on EditText click. I checked in emulator only.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" worked well for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that one reason for the keyboard not showing up is selecting an inputtype not supported by the specific Android device. For instance InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL will not work on my Asus Transformer (no keyboard shows up), while InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    et2.clearFocus();
    et2.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(et2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I meet the problem on Android N platform and resolve it by refocusing the editview.
I don`t know the real reason why the editview should be cleared first,but it works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe the soft keyboard may be over-layed by a Dialogfragment or something else

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you will need to post-delay showing keyboard command, so in my case, i did the following

```
editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }, 300);
```

Answer (score -2):

For getting the focus to particular edittext just add the  tag inside your edit text.

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etBox"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="enter into editbox"
    >
    <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
```

Comment: Archie's question is not about setting focus automatically on an edit text element, it is about the soft keyboard not showing up when an edit text element has focus.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question, you should remove it in order to avoid downvotes